# Filter count table query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 tables as following.

User

```
id         name 
---------------
1          john
2          raju
3          manu
4          raghu
```

friendtable

```
id  userid       recvId
------------------------
1   1         2
2   1         3
3   2         3
4   3         4
```

Is it possible to filter users by their friends count from  these tables.Please help me.

For eg :- range >=3 will result  : john,manu

range >3 and range <2 will result : raju
range <2  result : raghu

Comment: Yes. It's perfectly possible.

Comment: Are you asking how many times each user.id exists in the friendtable`'s two columns?

Comment: @jarlh yes. exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `UNION ALL` to get all id's from friendstable in one column. Join users table with that result.

Do a `GROUP BY`, adjust `HAVING` to decide what to return, e.g. at least 3 times etc.

```
select u.name
from users
join (select userid as id from friendtable
      union all
      select recvId as id from friendtable) f
  on u.id = f.id
group by u.name
having count(*) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM user a,friendtable b WHERE a.id=b.id AND  b.recvid>=3

SELECT name FROM  user a,friendtable b WHERE a.id=b.id and  b.recvid>3 AND b.recid<2

SELECT name FROM  user a,friendtable b WHERE a.id=b.id AND  b.recid<2
```